# Show that the complement of a plane is the union of boxes

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

Let $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ be the extended real line. Given $(\alpha,\beta)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, let $\mathcal{B}_{\alpha,\beta}$ be a box in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^3$ of any of these forms:

\begin{align} 
&(\alpha+\beta,\infty]\times [-\infty,\alpha]\times [-\infty,\beta], && (\alpha+\beta,\infty]\times [-\infty,\alpha)\times [-\infty,\beta), && (\alpha+\beta,\infty]\times [-\infty,\alpha]\times [-\infty,\beta),\nonumber \\
&(\alpha+\beta,\infty]\times [-\infty,\alpha)\times [-\infty,\beta], && [\alpha+\beta,\infty]\times [-\infty,\alpha]\times [-\infty,\beta), &&  [\alpha+\beta,\infty]\times [-\infty,\alpha)\times [-\infty,\beta], \nonumber\\
&[\alpha+\beta,\infty]\times [-\infty,\alpha)\times [-\infty,\beta), && [-\infty, \alpha+\beta)\times [a,\infty]\times [\beta,\infty], &&  [-\infty, \alpha+\beta)\times (\alpha,\infty]\times (\beta,\infty], \nonumber\\
&[-\infty, \alpha+\beta)\times [\alpha,\infty]\times (\beta,\infty], &&  [-\infty, \alpha+\beta)\times (\alpha,\infty]\times [\beta,\infty], &&  [-\infty, \alpha+\beta]\times [\alpha,\infty]\times (\beta,\infty], \nonumber\\
&[-\infty, \alpha+\beta]\times (\alpha,\infty]\times [\beta,\infty], &&  [-\infty, \alpha+\beta]\times (\alpha,\infty]\times (\beta,\infty]. && \nonumber
\end{align}

For instance,
$$
(\alpha+\beta,\infty]\times [-\infty,\alpha]\times [-\infty,\beta]\equiv \{(x,y,z)\in \bar{\mathbb{R}}^3: x>\alpha+\beta,y\leq \alpha, z\leq \beta \}.
$$

Let $P$ be a plane, $P\equiv  \{(x,y,z)\in \bar{\mathbb{R}}^3: x=y+z\}$.

I would like to formally show that
$$
\bar{\mathbb{R}}^3\setminus \{\cup_{(\alpha,\beta)\in \mathbb{R}^2} \mathcal{B}_{\alpha,\beta}\}=P
$$

Could you help?